# Unable to use CakePHP Digest Authentication for Rest API

Tags: rest, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, digest-authentication

Before beginning, full disclaimer, I have just started out with CakePHP, Digest Authentication and primarily referring to the Cookbook and StackOverflow for guidance.

Onto the problem at hand, I am trying to build a rather simple rest api (using [this](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html) as starting point and [this](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-restful-routes) for routing). Without authentication I have been able to get the routing working and the end point (as an example `/api/v1/notices.json`) is returning json response just as expected. All good till this point. The next step is to add digest authentication to the mix.

This is where things go south. Following the [Authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords) section of Cookbook, I did place the required code.

Here's the UsersController.php initialize method,

```
 public function initialize()
 {
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
      'authenticate' => [
          'Digest' => [
              'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'digest_hash'],
              'userModel' => 'Users'
          ],
      ],
      'storage' => 'Memory',
      'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
  ]);
}
```

Here's the NoticesController.php initialize method,

```
public function initialize()
{
  parent::initialize();
  $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Digest' => [
            'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'digest_hash'],
            'userModel' => 'Users'
        ],
    ],
    'storage' => 'Memory',
    'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
]);
}
```

Here's UsersTable.php beforeSave method,

```
public function beforeSave(Event $event)
{
    $entity = $event->getData('entity');

    // Make a password for digest auth.
    $entity->digest_hash = DigestAuthenticate::password(
        $entity->username,
        $entity->password,
        env('SERVER_NAME')
    );
    return true;
}
```

Using Postman each time I try to access `/api/v1/notices.json` supplying the my_username in username field and digest_hash value for the user in password field. Doing so I get Unauthorized message as part of json response. Following is the data being sent by Postman,

```
GET /api/v1/notices.json HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8765
Authorization: Digest username="my_username", realm="", nonce="", 
uri="/api/v1/notices.json", 
response="ab5a2441f5396e223efd48a0a0c205b9", opaque=""
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 715dbb84-ab72-8b68-bf77-5eee01b9cc2c
```

Trying to access the same endpoint from Google Chrome results in login pop ups one after another and doesn't go through at all.

Any help will be appreciated!

Update: Following is the database scheme for table users,

[image]

I am storing (for the time being) password in plain text and digest_hash for, well, storing hashed values.

Update 2: The response hash, I believe, is being generated by Postman. Although I did not specifically define values for realm, qop, nonce, etc. but they are being sent as part of header (refer image below),

[image]

And I am at fault here for storing digest_hash and password as binary(64). Should rather use blob (or varchar).

Comment: Where did you get the response hash from? Also your request lacks a nonce, and possibly the realm. And why binary (64)? I don't think a binary type will work, as it would result in the hash to be returned as a stream, which converts to `Resource id #%n` when casted to a string in the authenticator.

Comment: Updated the question with additional information. And I did check, the password is being converted to "Resource id #%n". Switching to blob.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Postman, and don't have time to try it right now, but the `WWW-Authenticate` header is a header sent from the server, Postman needs to send an `Authorization` header as shown in your example code above, and that one is missing the `nonce`, `realm`, `nc`, `cnonce` and `qop` values. I remember CakePHP being rather relaxed with digest validation, but AFAIR at least the nonce needs to to be valid, and I think all the other values must only be present. ps. blob is a binary type too ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the fact that you're supplying an empty string as realm in your postman request.

The [CakePHP documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-digest-authentication) states:

> The third parameter of DigestAuthenticate::password() must match the ‘realm’ config value defined when DigestAuthentication was configured in AuthComponent::$authenticate. This defaults to env('SCRIPT_NAME'). You may wish to use a static string if you want consistent hashes in multiple environments.

When you define your Digest password, you supply `env('SERVER_NAME')` as realm. This means that you wither have to replace this with an static string or change the request so you supply the correct realm.

**Example**

```
$entity->digest_hash = DigestAuthenticate::password(
    $entity->username,
    $entity->password,
    'My Realm'
);
```

Comment: I added static string but based on @ndm's comment, it looks like I need to get my data type's and digest authentication facts right first.

Comment: I'll improve my answer When I get around to it :)